# click on button to send adb command python

Tags: android, python

I would like to build a program to send adb command to mobile when I click
the button, I tried with the following code but the command is not send to device.

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
import subprocess

root = Tk()
root.title("MUT Tester")
root.geometry("500x500")

def button():

cmd= os.system("adb devices")


b = Button(root, text="Enter", width=30, height=2, command = lambda:(button))
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
b = Button(root, text="Enter", width=30, height=2, command = lambda:(button))
```

the button function is not being called by command when you click (replace button with a print statement to test). Remove the lambda and replace it with just command = button.

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax error**: *expected an intended block after function definition on line 12*

Fix:

```
def button():

    cmd= os.system("adb devices")
```

Comment: please, add a brief explanation og how/why it solves the problem